# In regards to CPU instructions, why is the result of an operation stored in the source register?

Tags: computer-architecture, cpu

Specifically when it comes to R-Type instructions, the format is

> operand, sR1, sR2, dR

where sR1, sR2 are source registers and dR is the destination register.

What I don't understand is why the operation

> ADD, R1, R2, R3

results in the sum of R2 and R3 being stored in R1. If R1 and R2 are the 'source registers' then shouldn't the sum of R1 and R2 be stored in R3, the destination register?

Comment: That sounds more like someone messed up the naming in the documentation

Comment: Please edit your question to cite your sources and provide more context.  Why do you think that ADD, R1, R2, R3 has that effect?   Can you cite where you read that?  Are you asking about MIPS specifically?

Comment: If you do ask about MIPS, that’s an architecture that most have forgotten by now.